# why there are only 3 elements in my /etc/file?

Tags: group

My system is debian 7.8. [It is said](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.user-group-databases.html#sect.etc-group) that there are four elements on `/etc/group` file ,

```
group_name 
Password 
Group ID (GID): 
Group List:
```

Why are there are only three elements in my `/etc/group` file ?

```
root@debian:/home/debian# cat  /etc/group
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:
```

In my situation:
the first column is group name;
the second column is password,x stand for the fact that the password is  ommitted  here （right?)
the last column is Group List?
Take the last row  `adm:x:4:` for example, there are 4 members in the group `adm`?
If so,how can I get all of them ?

Comment: "There are 4 membes in group `adm`" Why do you thinks so? The documentation **clearly** states, as you repeated yourself here, that the `4` stands for **Group ID**.

Answer (score 1):

In each case here, the fourth field is empty. If, for example, you added a user to the `root` group, that user's username would appear after the final colon:

```
root:x:0:someuser
```

Additional extra usernames are then comma-separated.

The `passwd` file/database tells the kernel every user's *primary* group - the fourth field contains the numeric group ID, which relates to the group in `/etc/group`, so to take the example of the `adm` group - the first field is the name, the second is the password (and yes, the "x" here means that the group has no password), the third is the numerical group ID (the kernel uses this to find the group name for display in long file listings, for example), and the fourth is the list of users for whom `adm` is a supplementary group. Remember that each user's primary group is indicated in the `passwd` file.